# Error with Azure backup - Time not valid for database

Tags: azure

Recently we've had one of our web services fail its Azure database backups with the following error.

```
The specified point in time, '11/24/2021 16:57:50', is not valid for database 'R6tvK6Nc9W'. Valid points in time should be between '11/24/2021 16:59:48' and '11/24/2021 17:03:50' inclusive.
```

The timestamps vary, but in each case the top of the time range is exactly 6 minutes from the specified time. The error is coming from Azure, and up until recently everything has been working fine without any issues, no major code changes have occurred on our end for some time.

I'm more or less new to Azure, having only recently taken over from the previous developer who worked on this, so if this is something obvious or common I apologise, it wasn't covered in the handover I was given.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database is part of Failover Group and remove it before starting the restore.